# Change parent div based on child class

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the background colour of an  element when my mobile menu is open, but struggling to find the javascript to do so.

Here's what I'm trying to do exactly.

I'd like to change the background colour of the `<a href="//online-port-ac-uk-7429396.hs-sites.com/online-learning" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" role="menuitem">How you'll Learn</a>` when the `<div class="child-trigger"><i></i></div>` has "child-open" in it

At the moment this is my JS:

```
$( ".child-open" )
    .parents()
        .addClass( "has-child-open" );
```

But having no luck with that.

This is the page in question - http://online-port-ac-uk-7429396.hs-sites.com/

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly. Your question needs to include _all_ the necessary(!) code to reproduce your problem, not half of it on some live website (where it might simply disappear from, after the problem got solved, which would make this question worthless to future readers.)

Comment: _“At the moment this is my JS:”_ - executed _when_? If you want this to work dynamically, after the user has clicked to open a specific sub-menu item - then you need to execute it inside some sort of click event handler or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do using addClassNameListener to check child class is a change or not

```js
function addClassNameListener(elemId, callback) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
    var lastClassName = elem.className;
    window.setInterval( function() {   
       var className = elem.className;
        if (className !== lastClassName) {
            callback();   
            lastClassName = className;
        }
    },10);
}
$( "#test" ).click(function() {
   $("#child").toggleClass("child-open");
});
addClassNameListener('child', function(){
  $( "#parent" ).removeClass("has-child-open");
  if($("#child").hasClass( "child-open" )){
      $("#parent" ).addClass( "has-child-open");
  }
});
```

```css
.has-child-open{background-color: red;}

.child-open{background-color: green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id ="parent"href="//online-port-ac-uk-7429396.hs-sites.com/online-learning" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" role="menuitem">How you'll Learn</div></a>


<div id="child" class="child-trigger"><i></i>child</div>

<button id="test">change</button >
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use JavaScript at all - you can simply use CSS:

```css
.child-open {
    background-color: #c3d5fa;
}
```

When the element has the `child-open` class, it automatically applies the `background-color` style to it.

If you're looking for a JavaScript only method, you could inject CSS into the page:

```js
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = `
    .child-open {
        background-color: #c3d5fa;
    }
`;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```